# Is the depletetion layer of an np junction really (completely) depleted?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

My confusion stems from the energy-band diagram across the pn junction (bottom of post).

One the one hand, the energy levels ($E_c$, $E_v$) change **continuously**, on the other hand, I know that they are governed by the carrier densities:

$$E_c = E_f + k_B T \ln\frac{N_c}{n_0}$$
$$E_v = E_f - k_B T \ln\frac{N_v}{p_0}$$

If the carrier concentration is zero along the entire depletion layer, then wouldn't $E_c$   and $E_v$ be constant?

Another thing that I just realized when typing the equations, how can the concentrations be 0 if there is no such thing as $ln(0)$?

[image: pn energy diagram]

Comment: I am now pretty sure that the equations for $E_c$ and $E_v$ do not apply in the depletion layer; but, since they do apply at the edges of the layer, they can be used to calculate the built-in potential. That being said, I cannot figure out WHY they don't apply in the depletion layer, i.e. what underlying assumption do they violate? Also, what are the correct equations in the depletion layer?

Comment: There's an electric field through the depletion region, correct?

Comment: There is no external field, just the field that's created due to the diffusion of the charge carriers across the junction.

Comment: Correct, there's a field through the depletion region even with zero external field.  So, if there's a mobile charge carrier within the depletion region, it will (a) stay there or (b) be swept out by the electric field there.

Comment: I am not sure that this answers my question. What I don't understand is: what equations describe $E_{c,v}$ as a function of $x$?

Comment: YofA, this is your title question:  *"Is the depletetion layer of an np junction really (completely) depleted?"*.